# finding xpath of dropdown for application developed in angular

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

HTML code for the dropdown:

```
 <div class="margin-bottom">

      <select ng-class="{'invalid-select':(selectedItem == '-1' &amp;&amp; submitted)}" class="select-lg select-custom ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required" name="items" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items" required="" ng-change="onChange()" style="">

     <option value="" selected="selected" class="">Select One</option>
     <option label="Stage Test" value="number:682">Stage Test</option>
     <option label="automation 1" value="number:687">automation 1</option>
     <option label="automation 3" value="number:688">automation 3</option>
     <option label="new co" value="number:690">new co</option></select>
 </div>
```

I am using XPath to get the element using :

```
Select companySelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@ng-model='selectedItem']")));
```

Comment: is the xpath is able to identify the element in chrome dev tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

While constructing the `xpath` for the `Select` element, you have tried to take help of the attribute `ng-model`. This attribute is pretty common with Applications built with `AngularJS` and when used as the only attribute to construct an `xpath` it may not identify an element as a unique element on the `HTML DOM`.

As per the `HTML` you provided, the `Select` tag have a `name`. As per best practices we should look out for the `id` or `name` locator first as they are always unique. Consider keeping your steps simple so it is easy to debug incase of errors. Here is the sample code block as per your HTML which selects **Stage Test** from the dropdown:

```
WebElement my_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.name("items"))
Select companySelect = new Select(my_dropdown);
companySelect.selectByVisibleText("Stage Test");
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this is working at my side :- I have used your HTML

```
//*[@name='items' and @ng-model='selectedItem']
```

Screenshot :- [image]

I hope this will work for you.

If want to select an option from this list use

```
//*[@name='items' and @ng-model='selectedItem']/option[3]
```

It will now select "automation 1"